# Override default margins/padding around email header images in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, margin

I'm coding an email, and the hero image is misaligned slightly and only in Outlook.

[image: The problem]

I've seen and tried some answers to this question already (Setting the font size to 0, removing the "margin", adding another table just for the image), but all of the answers were several years old. I think there's a new update in Outlook that is causing this issue.

My code is here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<!--[if !mso]><!-->  
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<!--<![endif]-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
<title></title>  
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>  
    <style type="text/css">  
    table {border-collapse: collapse !important;}
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>  
<body style="background-color:#eeeeee; Margin:0; padding:0; min-width:100%;">
<style type="text/css">
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}  

*[class=mobile]{display:none;}

@media only screen and (max-width:650px) {   
*[class=desktop]{display:none !important;  
    background:none!important;}  
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 649px) {
 *[class="column"],
 *[class="two-column"] {
         width: 100%!important;
        max-width: 649px!important;
 }
*[class="rightrail"] {
    max-width: 100%!important;
}
*[class="rightrail"] img {
    width: 100%!important;
}
   *[class="nomobile"] {
        overflow: hidden !important;
 float: none !important;
 display: none !important;
 line-height:0% !important;  
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  [class*=wrapper] .app {
     width: 70%!important;
  }  
      [class*=wrapper] .app-text span {
     font-size:15px!important;
     font-weight:bold;
  }
      [class*=wrapper] .app-text span span {
 font-size:7px!important;
 font-weight:bold;
  }

    *[class=desktop]{
            display:block!important;
            font-size: 14px!important; 
            max-height: 100%!important; 
            line-height: 20px!important; 
            text-align: center;!Important;
        }
    div[class=desktop]{
            display:block!important;
            font-size: 14px!important; 
            max-height: 100%!important; 
            line-height: 20px!important; 
            margin: 0 auto!important;
            text-align:center!important;
        }
   *[class="mobileonly"] {
        overflow: visible !important;
 float: none !important;
 display: block !important;
 line-height:100% !important;  
}
    *[class=desktop] table {
            display: inline-block!important;
        font-size: 14px!important;
        max-height: 100%!important;
        line-height: 20px!important;
        width: 100%!important;
        text-align: center!Important;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 140px!important;    
        }
   *[class="padding"] {
 padding: 0 5% !important;  
}
    *[class=desktop] a {
            display:block!important;
            font-size: 14px!important; 
            max-height: 100%!important; 
            line-height: 20px!important; 
            padding: 8px 20px!important;
        }
    *[class="column"],
     *[class="two-column"] {
         width: 90%!important;
 }

    }

</style>
        <center class="wrapper" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; background-color: #eeeeee">  
    <br class="nomobile">
    <!--Pre Header-->
    <div class="header" style="max-width:650px;"> 
      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;">
            <tr>
            <td style="padding:0;">
    <![endif]-->
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-spacing:0; Margin:0 auto; width:100%; max-width:650px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:0;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="25">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="600" valign="top">
            <![endif]--> 
         <!--[if !(gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <div style="width:5%; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; mso-hide: all!important;">&nbsp;</div>
               <![endif]--> 

        <!--[if !(gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <div style="width:5%; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; mso-hide: all!important;">&nbsp;</div>
               <![endif]--> 
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td>
                        <td width="25">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
                    <![endif]--></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!--Header-->
<div class="header" style="max-width:650px;"> 
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;">
                <tr>
                <td style="padding:0;">
       <![endif]-->
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-spacing:0; Margin:0 auto; width:100%; max-width:650px; background-color: #0079c2;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:0;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="25">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="600" valign="top">
                <![endif]--> 
        <!--[if !(gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    <div style="width:5%; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; mso-hide: all!important;">&nbsp;</div>
               <![endif]-->

        <div style="width:90%; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;" >
             <tr>
              <td width="100%" class="inner"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0; padding: 0; margin: 0" >
                  <tr>
                    <td width="100%" class="inner"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0; padding: 0; margin: 0" >
                        <tr>
                          <td width="30%" align="left"><a href="https://www.bcbst.com/"><img src="http://image.bcbst-email.com/lib/fe9612717c60077f75/m/1/logo-white_2.png" alt="BlueCross BlueShield of Tn" width="134" height="55" border="0" style="display: block; max-width: 134px; color: #ffffff; background: #0079C2; font-size:9px;"/></a></td>
                          <td width="55%" align="right"><p style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color:#ffffff; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 12px;"><a href="%%view_email_url%%" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration:none;">View Online</a></p></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

        <!--[if !(gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    <div style="width:5%; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; mso-hide: all!important;">&nbsp;</div>
                   <![endif]--> 
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td>
                        <td width="25">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
                    <![endif]--></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<!--Header--> 

<!--Hero Image-->
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%; max-width:650px!important; padding: 0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://image.bcbst-email.com/lib/fe9612717c60077f75/m/1/Health+Foundation+Header+V2.jpg" style="width:100%; display:block; max-width: 650; color: #0079C2; font-weight:bold; background: #ffffff; font-size:14px;" alt="A New Focus for our Health Foundation" border="0" width="100%" class="hero"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--Hero Image-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this CSS Cheatsheet that will reset most of the styles across different email providers, add it before any of your styles

```
/* Client-specific Styles */

#outlook a {
padding: 0;
}
/* Force Outlook to obtain a "view in browser" menu link. */

body {
width: 100% !important;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
/* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes, while not breaking desktop design. */

.ExternalClass {
width: 100%;
}
/* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */

.ExternalClass,
.ExternalClass p,
.ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font,
.ExternalClass td,
.ExternalClass div {
line-height: 100%;
}
/* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing.*/

#backgroundTable {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100% !important;
line-height: 100% !important;
}

img {
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
border: none;
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

a img {
border: none;
text-decoration: none;
border: none;
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

.image_fix {
display: block;
}

p {
margin: 0px 0px !important;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
}

table td {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

.removemobile {
display: none;
}
/*STYLES*/
/*################################################*/
/*IPAD STYLES*/
/*################################################*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 612px) {
a[href^="tel"],
a[href^="sms"] {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
/* or whatever your want */
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
}
.mobile_link a[href^="tel"],
.mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
text-decoration: default;
color: #ffffff !important;
pointer-events: auto;
cursor: default;
}
table[class=devicewidth] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
}
td[class=devicewidth] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
}
table[class=devicewidthinner] {
width: 92%!important;
text-align: center!important;
float: none!important;
margin: auto!important;
}
td[class=devicewidthinner] {
width: 92%!important;
text-align: center!important;
float: none!important;
margin: auto!important;
}
table[class=centered] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
clear: both;
}
td[class=centered] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
clear: both;
}
td[class="logo"] {
width: 100%!important;
float: left;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
td[class="menu"] {
width: 100%!important;
float: left;
}
table[class=fullspread] {
width: 100%!important;
clear: both;
}
table[class=fullwidth] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
clear: both;
}
td[class=fullwidth] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
clear: both;
}
td[class="aligncenter"] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
}
table[class="aligncenter"] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
}
table[class="buttoncenter"] {
float: none!important;
text-align: center!important;
display: inline-block!important;
clear: both;
}
img[class="imageinline"] {
display: inline!important;
}
img[class="fullwidth"] {
display: inline!important;
width: 100%!important;
}
td[class="paddingtop"] {
padding-top: 15px!important;
}
.buttonleft {
display: inherit!important;
}
.removemobile {
width: 100%!important;
display: block;
}
table[class="halfwidth"] {
width: 50%!important;
}
table[class="mghide"] {
display: none!important;
}
td[class="mghide"] {
display: none!important;
}
}
/*##############################################*/
/*IPHONE STYLES*/
/*##############################################*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
a[href^="tel"],
a[href^="sms"] {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
/* or whatever your want */
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
}
.mobile_link a[href^="tel"],
.mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
text-decoration: default;
color: #ffffff !important;
pointer-events: auto;
cursor: default;
}
table[class=devicewidth] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
}
td[class=devicewidth] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
}
table[class=devicewidthinner] {
width: 92%!important;
text-align: center!important;
float: none!important;
margin: auto!important;
}
td[class=devicewidthinner] {
width: 92%!important;
text-align: center!important;
float: none!important;
margin: auto!important;
}
table[class=fullspread] {
width: 100%!important;
clear: both;
}
table[class=fullwidth] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
clear: both;
}
td[class=fullwidth] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
clear: both;
}
table[class=centered] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
clear: both;
}
td[class=centered] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
clear: both;
}
td[class="logo"] {
width: 100%!important;
float: left;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
td[class="menu"] {
width: 100%!important;
float: left;
}
td[class="aligncenter"] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
}
table[class="aligncenter"] {
width: 100%!important;
text-align: center!important;
}
table[class="buttoncenter"] {
float: none!important;
text-align: center!important;
display: inline-block!important;
clear: both;
}
img[class="imageinline"] {
display: inline!important;
}
img[class="fullwidth"] {
display: inline!important;
width: 100%!important;
}
td[class="paddingtop"] {
padding-top: 15px!important;
}
.buttonleft {
display: inherit!important;
}
.removemobile {
width: 100%!important;
display: block;
}
table[class="halfwidth"] {
width: 50%!important;
}
table[class="mghide"] {
display: none!important;
}
td[class="mghide"] {
display: none!important;
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is a really handy tool and I'll definitely use it, but I already tried the padding:0 solution and it didn't fix my issue...

Comment: Do you have the viewport meta in your HTML? You can also global reset just in case `*, * *{padding: 0; margin: 0, box-sizing: border-box}`